# Does normal force always point perpendicular to the surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram, string

I drew arrow #2 on an AP Physics C assignment, but my teacher said it was wrong and took away a point since it was not perfectly vertical. I feel like it could be arrow #2 though with the information present?

[image: Pulley Problem]